# intento meter el mainLayout en una pestaña determinada porque no me funciona

Tags: c++, qt

```
tabs=new QTabWidget();
    tab1 = new QWidget(this);
    tab1->setObjectName(QString("tab1"));
    tabs->addTab(tab1, QString("TAB 1"));
    tab2 = new QWidget(this);
    tab2->setObjectName(QString("tab2"));
    tabs->addTab(tab2, QString("TAB 2"));

    mainLayout->addLayout(horizontalLayoutBd,1);
    mainLayout->addWidget(combos,1);
    mainLayout->addLayout( horizontalLayoutTab,4);
    mainLayout->addLayout(horizontalLayoutBtn,2);
    mainLayout->addWidget(statusBar);
    //mainLayout->addWidget(tab1);
    tab1->setLayout(mainLayout);
    centralWidget->setLayout(mainLayout);

    setCentralWidget(centralWidget);*
```

Comment: No entiendo la pregunta. ¿Qué es lo que no funciona?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`QTabWidget` no dispone de un *layout* donde ir añadiendo los diferentes *tabs* o pestañas sino que se limita a mostrar el widget correspondiente a la pestaña seleccionada, quedando ocultos el resto de widgets.

¿Cómo se añade entonces una pestaña a un `QTabWidget`? Así:

```
tabs->addTab(tab1 , tr("TAB 1"));
tabs->addTab(tab2 , tr("TAB 2"));
```

Que es algo que ya estás haciendo... ¿Qué te falla entonces? Esto:

```
//mainLayout->addWidget(tab1);
tab1->setLayout(mainLayout);
```

Lo que tienes que hacer es añadir `tab` al *layout* en vez de intentar añadir `tab1`y `tab2`:

```
mainLayout->addWidget(tabs);
```

Lo que no puedes hacer es tener un `QTabWidget` y usar el *layout* de una de sus pestañas como layout central de un diálogo... no funciona así.

---

Copiado de un comentario:

> quiero meter dentro de tab1 todo y para tab 2 crear otro interfaz

Una posible solución:

```
// Controles que van a estar dentro del tab
QLineEdit* lineEdit = new QLineEdit;

// Creamos el layout
QLayout* tab1Layout = new QHBoxLayout;
tab1Layout->addWidget(lineEdit);

// Creamos el tab
QWidget* tab1 = new QWidget;
// tab1->setObjectName(QString("tab1")); <--- innecesario
tab1->setLayout(tab1Layout);

QTabWidget* tabs = new QTabWidget;
// Insertamos el tab en el QTabWidget
tabs->addTab(tab1, "TAB 1");
```

Comment: Entonces como añado lo que quiero dentro de cada pestaña?

Comment: @AntonioVelosoGomez cada pestaña es un _widget_... luego puede actuar como un contenedor de objetos... añade un _layout_ al _widget_ y después inserta controles en dicho _layout_

Comment: es lo que hacia en tab1->setLayout(mainLayout);

Comment: @AntonioVelosoGomez Pero es lo que te he dicho en la respuesta. No puedes pretender que el layout central de la ventana sea el layout de un tab... son cosas diferentes

Comment: No lo entiendo, quiero meter dentro de tab1 todo y para tab 2 crear otro interfaz. Pero no me deja meter dentro del tab nada mas que layout asi que le meto el mainLayout probe a crear otro mainLayout llamado mainLayout2 y añadirle mainLayout y mainLatyout2 meterlo en centralWidget pero tambien debe estar mal

Comment: @AntonioVelosoGomez revisa la respuesta, que la he editado

Comment: Hoy estoy un poco espeso. Gracias por la ayuda y por tu paciencia